# Energy transfers in boiling a liquid?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

When you boil a liquid the KE stays the same (as temp is the same), so where does the extra energy go? I know the extra energy put in breaks bonds between the molecules/ atoms, but once it has broken the bonds where does the energy go?

And where does the potential energy in a liquid go- as (ideal) gases don't have PE? I've heard it's turned to latent heat, but what is this, how is it stored?

Comment: The energy is still in the water. If you put your hands in boiling water, you can feel where the energy went. Try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**the "extra" energy leaves the system in the form of fast moving water molecules, aka steam.**

dont forget that the average velocity of gaseous water molecules trump that of liquid phase molecules, which are bound together by hydrogen bonds. a massive amount of heat is required to overcome those H-bonds to create free water molecules (gas phase) which can then leave the system into the atmosphere at very high velocity. this is the reason why boiling water doesn't rise above $100^\circ C$ when it is allowed to boil freely (the steam is allowed to leave).

but if you completely close the system, such as in a pressure cooker, you can take water up to $120^\circ C$ easily. then it is more clear that there is no "extra" or unaccounted energy.